# ngFor rendering html columns per repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the following JSON result:

```
queryResults =[
    {
        name:cliff,
        age:30,
        hobby:golf,
        email;cliff@gmail.com
    },
    {
        productname:coke,
        productlife:2,
        price:60,
        popularity:1
    }    
]
```

as the result is coming dynamicaly i have to loop through they key and key value to get the property name and value using 
the following code

```
<md-card  *ngFor='let result of queryResults | keys'>
 <md-card-title-group>
          <md-card-subtitle class="card-details">
              <table class="table">

                    <tr *ngFor='let  cont of result.value | keys'   >
                             <td class="text-bold">{{cont.key}} :</td>
                             <td  > {{cont.value}}</td>
                    </tr>     
              </table>
          </md-card-subtitle>

    </md-card-title-group>

</md-card>
```

which would produce result in the following format

```
  name: cliff
  age: 30
  hobby:golf
  email:cliff@gmail.com

  productname:coke
  productlife:2
  price:60
  popularity:1
```

what should i do if i want to render it to the following format?

```
name: cliff     age:30
hobby:golf      email:cliff@gmail.com

productname:coke   productlife:2
price:60           popularity:1
```

plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/jaYdwFRTE2Kdwslx7sl0?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution thanks to MarcoS suggestion

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <md-card *ngFor='let result of queryResults | keys'>
      <md-card-title-group>
        <md-card-subtitle class="card-details">  
          <div *ngFor='let cont of result.value | keys; let i =index'>
           <div [ngClass]="{row:i % 2 == 1}">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-bold">{{cont.key}} :</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">{{cont.value}}</div>
           </div>
          </div>
        </md-card-subtitle>
      </md-card-title-group>
    </md-card>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great! This is what I really meant... :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your're using an html/css framework (like Bootstrap), you could use it's own grid system...
For example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <md-card *ngFor='let result of queryResults | keys'>
      <md-card-title-group>
        <md-card-subtitle class="card-details">  
          <div *ngFor='let cont of result.value | keys' *ngIf="$index % 2 == 0" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 text-bold">{{cont.key}} :</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">{{cont.value}}</div>
          </div>
        </md-card-subtitle>
      </md-card-title-group>
    </md-card>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you do include `bootstrap.css`? It shoud definitely work! Please note `class="col col-xs-6"` should be better written as `class="col-xs-6"`... Just updated my answer...

Comment: You're right, sorry!!! I did now understand my mistake... You shoud add the "row" class only when the $index of the ngFor is even (0, 2, 4, ...). Just updated my answer, hope it's working as expected, now...

Comment: i have created a plunk based on your solution https://plnkr.co/edit/jaYdwFRTE2Kdwslx7sl0?p=preview you can see that after adding *ngIf="$index % 2 == 0" nothing is rendered

Comment: You are right, sorry again... The fact is you can't use *ngFor and *ngIf on the same line... Unfortunately I'm just starting with Angular2, so can't let your plunk work... Though, I think the logic is this: `use a <row> only when index is even`... :-)

Comment: weird that you cant have it on the same line, it should at least throw an exception instead of not rendering anthing

Comment: Yes, it does throw (if you open developer's console you can see it... :-().